# How to pass "this" to point the event starter in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to pass a buttons object to a function and access its properties from that function.
My button :

```
<RaisedButton label="Primary" id = "1" onTouchTap={()=>this.buttonPress(this)}  primary={true} />
```

My function :

```
buttonPress = (event) => {
        console.log(event);
    }
```

All of the code is in a separate component which i am using in my main component. The problem is when i press the button it is not passing the buttons object to the function it is sending the whole component. How can i get only the buttons object?

Comment: In pure javascript you can use `event.target`.

Comment: you can still do that in React. `onTouchTap={event=>this.buttonPress(event.target)}`

Comment: `onTouchTap={this.buttonPress.bind(this)}`

Comment: none is woring. i keep getting the `span` or `div` based on where i'm clicking on the button(on text or not)@rlemon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: My original answer (below), as Ardentum pointed out, logs clicked DOM element. Try doing something like this instead:

```
<RaisedButton 
    ref={(button) => { this.RaisedButton = button; }}
    onTouchTap={()=>this.buttonPress( this.RaisedButton )}
/>
```

*Original answer:*
*this* in `onTouchTap={()=>this.buttonPress(this)}` refers to the whole component in which you render the `<RaisedButton (...) />`. In order to pass the button, which is being *TouchTapped* you could use

```
onTouchTap={(event)=>this.buttonPress(event)}
```

and then

```
buttonPress = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target);
}
```

Comment: In this case `event.target` refers to DOM node, not React component.

Comment: I tried this. It returns a `<span>` if i click on the text of the button and returns a `<div>` when i click within the box but not on the text. Neither returns me the `RaisedButton`.

Comment: @JanStachera it is working and giving me the `RaisedButton` object but is there any way that i can access attributes of it? i tried `event.target.id` and `event.id` none returns me the id. Could you help me solve this ?

Comment: got it working also thank you very much for your help @JanStachera

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is:

```
onTouchTap={this.buttonPress.bind(this, someProperty)}
```

With event handler like this:

```
buttonPress (someProperty) {
    console.log(someProperty);
}
```

So, instead of getting access to RaisedButton properties, you can just bind event handler with the props you need.

Comment: i tried `bind(this, id)` and `bind(this, this.id)`. 1st one gives me error and second one returns nothing.

Comment: In your example you can pass it as constant: `onTouchTap={this.buttonPress.bind(this, 1)}`. Bind is a [standard JavaScript function method](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). And variable that you pass there as parameter is just a variable from current scope.